# ImageMagick : ImageCoderSignatureMismatch `miff'

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've updated my version of ImageMagick and its bindings for PHP.

I've installed ImageMagick-7.0.4-9-Q16-x64,
and php_imagick-3.4.3-7.0-nts-vc14-x64,
running on PHP 7.0.10.

The command-line seems to work well since I've managed to execute a simple `magick convert image.png -resize 50% imageSmall.png` successfully.

The problem is that a PHP script who ran successfully on ImageMagick 6.8.x (I don't remember very well), but can't do it with this version.

It gave me the following error :

```
ImageCoderSignatureMismatch `miff': 210 != 610 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1342
```

Sometimes it shows me `Unable to set the image format` instead, I don't really know why.

I've found where in my code this error was triggered :

```
public function init(){
    var_dump('begin init fcrender canvas');
    if($this->_canvas == null){
        $this->_canvas = new Imagick();
        /////// It's the following line :
        $this->_canvas->newImage($this->_width, $this->_height, 'transparent', 'miff');
        /////////////////////////////////
        $this->_filename = 'image';
        $this->_extension = 'png';
    }
}
```

So why does this error come from ? Thanks you for your help ! :)

Comment: Hi, if emcconville's answer is correct, you should be seeing an warning message when PHP loads the Imagick module. Are you not seeing that? If you aren't please could you say how you're installing Imagick as I'll need to investigate why that error isn't being triggered.

Comment: No warning is displayed, neither on screen nor in php error log. :/

I installed Imagemagick using the Windows Binary Realease "ImageMagick-7.0.4-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe" in C:\imagemagick7_0_4\
I've configured manually my environment variables : PATH contains "C:\imagemagick7_0_4\", MAGICK_HOME and MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH are "C:\imagemagick7_0_4\modules\coders\".

I tested `magick convert afile.png -resize 50% afile-small.png` in command line and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think php_imagick is simply not compatible with ImageMagick7.x.x.

I downloaded and installed ImageMagick6.9.3 that I found here : http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/

(To install, I simply the folder in `C:\imagemagick\` and put the content of "bin\" at the top-level, in `C:\imagemagick\`.
Then I copied all the CORE_RL_*.dll in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\` .)

This works perfectly in PHP 7.0.10 with imagick3.4.3 downloadable here : https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: "I think php_imagick is simply not compatible with ImageMagick7.x.x" yes it is. Yes it is https://travis-ci.org/mkoppanen/imagick/builds/202421469 The only thing is that you can't mix and match versions of Imagick with ImageMagick.

https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick#installing-on-windows
"Once compiled, Imagick should be run with the same version of ImageMagick that it was compiled against. Running against a different version of ImageMagick is known to cause stability issues, and so is not recommended or supported."

Answer (score 1):

This means that the wrong module was loaded. The `210 != 610` are the version signature of the miff module, so IM 7 is expected miff `610`, but IM 6's `210` was loaded.

A couple options to fix.

- Uninstall all ImageMagick 6 resources.
- Reinstall ImageMagick 7 to an isolated location, and use `$MAGICK_HOME` environment variable.
- Define `MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH` environment variable to correct module path.

More info @ [Resources documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#modules).

Comment: I've uninstalled al existing occurrence of ImageMagick on my computer, and installed a new copy of ImageMagick 7.0.4 at a location never used before.
So, I've three environnement variables :
- Path : "C:\imagemagick7_0_4\"
- MAGICK_HOME and MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH : "C:\imagemagick7_0_4\modules\coders\"

Is that right ?

Comment: First option should work. Other two would be preferred if you're developing a solution with both versions, or need to quickly switch between the two.

Comment: Hmmmm, it doesn't seems to work :/ I got the same error.